# Loop through an array with jQuery returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Im trying to loop through an array and return data in order only I cant seem to return the data, I receive `undefined`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Liamatvenn/UvNw3/2/

**My Array**

```
var people = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'Brian Nicoll'
}, {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Gordon Sales'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Lorman E. Correa'
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Mark Moor'
}, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Richard Paisley'
}, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'S. Sivalingham'
}, {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Tony Coleman'
}];

var counter = 0;

(function nextFade() {
    counter++;
    var figure = $('<figure style="float:left; width:130px; height:30px;" />');
    var information = '<figcaption><h6>Meet ' + people.name + '</h6></figcaption>';
    figure.html(information).appendTo('.interactive-banner-faces').hide().fadeIn(100, function () {
        if (counter < 7) {
            nextFade();
        } else {
            $('.interactive-banner-faces').children(':nth-child(12n+1), :nth-child(12n+2), :nth-child(12n+3)').addClass('rightTxt');

            $('.interactive-banner').on('mouseenter', function () {
                $('.textbox').css('z-index', '9999')
                $('.overlay').stop().animate({
                    'top': '-450px'
                }, 200, 'easeInCirc');
            }).on('mouseleave', function () {
                $('.textbox').css('z-index', '-1')
                $('.overlay').stop().animate({
                    'top': '0'
                }, 600, 'easeOutCirc');
            });
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Each person has their own object. I.E `console.log(people[0].name);` will give you Brian Nicoll

Comment: people[counter-1].name, probably u want use counter as your indice

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to put the index `people[counter].name`

```
(function nextFade() {

        counter++;
        var figure = $('<figure style="float:left; width:130px; height:30px;" />');
        var information = '<figcaption><h6>Meet ' + people[counter].name + '</h6></figcaption>';
        figure.html(information).appendTo('.interactive-banner-faces').hide().fadeIn(100, function () {
            if (counter < 7) {
                nextFade();
            } else {

                $('.interactive-banner-faces').children(':nth-child(12n+1), :nth-child(12n+2), :nth-child(12n+3)').addClass('rightTxt');

                $('.interactive-banner').on('mouseenter', function () {


    $('.textbox').css('z-index', '9999')

                    $('.overlay').stop().animate({
                        'top': '-450px'
                    }, 200, 'easeInCirc');
                }).on('mouseleave', function () {

                     $('.textbox').css('z-index', '-1')

                    $('.overlay').stop().animate({
                        'top': '0'
                    }, 600, 'easeOutCirc');
                });

            }
        });
    })();
```

Comment: As counter is incremented before people is returned **counter++;** you will need to use **people[counter-1].name**. Or for readabilty you could move **counter++;** to after **var information=..**

Answer (score 3):

you use `people.name` which is undefined because `people` is an `Array`
use `people[i].name`

Comment: @Liam This would be **people[counter - 1].name** in your code

Comment: see that fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UvNw3/7/